# enumerating NSMutableAttributedString - not a UIColor object?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

It happened (probably) due to migrating to swift 3 - before that it was working.

here's the String :

```
<![CDATA[<h2><font color="#aa2c2c">some colored text</font></h2><br />
some non-attributed text..]]>
```

My idea is to paint non-attributed text to black or white due to a color scheme.

to do so (dear Android, you did it all by yourself), I enumerate attributes:

```
 text.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(0..<text.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
                        for (attribute, object) in attributes {
                            if let textColor = object as? UIColor{
                                 NSLog("textColor = \(textColor) red = \(Utils.redColor)") 
         if (!textColor.isEqual(Utils.greyColor) && !textColor.isEqual(Utils.redColor)){
         text.setAttributes(textAttributes , range: range)
        }
      }
    }
```

So, what I get in logs are : `textColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1  red = Optional(UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.666667 0.172549 0.172549 1)`

I need to compare this `textColor` with special colors , and if it's none of them - I paint it to black or white due to a color scheme

now , neither Utils.redColor nor Utils.greyColor which are instances of UIColor doesn't trigger, although they both exist in the attributed text.

It worked in Swift 2, but after mirgrating to Swift 3 the condition doesn't trigger.

Comment: `Utils.redColor` is constructed how?

Comment: @Larme Utils.redColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255.0, alpha: alpha)